# How to get WAN IPv4 & IPv6 address into variable(s) using Powershell as opposed to relying on external A & AAAA DynDNS zones

Tags: powershell, networking, dns, ip, ipv6

This is what I am playing around with at the moment to grab my internal LAN IPv4/IPv6 addresses into each of my dual IP stack variables:

```powershell-5
# This is a one liner(-ish) to get my LAN_IPv4 and IPv6 addresses:

# Begin
$ipv4 = Get-NetIPAddress -AddressFamily IPv4 -InterfaceIndex $(Get-NetConnectionProfile |
    Select-Object -ExpandProperty InterfaceIndex) | Select-Object -ExpandProperty IPAddress
$ipv6 = Get-NetIPAddress -AddressFamily IPv6 -InterfaceIndex $(Get-NetConnectionProfile |
    Select-Object -ExpandProperty InterfaceIndex) | Select-Object -ExpandProperty IPAddress
echo IPv4: $ipv4
echo IPv6: $ipv6

# Will be using this for external WAN IP (Below)
# [System.Net.Dns]::GetHostEntry('my.ddnshost.tld')
```

The only way I can figure to grab my WAN IPv4 and IPv6 Addresses is to use a DNS host records 'A' and 'AAAA'

```powershell-5
Working Local IPv4 and IPv6 address 
#BEGIN 
$ipv4 = Get-NetIPAddress -AddressFamily IPv4 -InterfaceIndex $(Get-NetConnectionProfile |
    Select-Object -ExpandProperty InterfaceIndex) | Select-Object -ExpandProperty IPAddress
$ipv6 = Get-NetIPAddress -AddressFamily IPv6 -InterfaceIndex $(Get-NetConnectionProfile |
    Select-Object -ExpandProperty InterfaceIndex) | Select-Object -ExpandProperty IPAddress

#Use DNS to Resolve WAN_IPv4 and WAN_IPv6 via [Systems.Net.Dns]
$ddns_ipv4 = ([System.Net.DNS]::GetHostAddresses('ipv4.ddns.tld') | 
    Where-Object {$_.AddressFamily -eq "InterNetwork"} | select-object IPAddressToString)[0].IPAddressToString
$ddns_ipv6 = ([System.Net.DNS]::GetHostAddresses('ipv6zone.ddns.tld') |
    Where-Object {$_.AddressFamily -eq "InterNetwork"} | select-object IPAddressToString)[0].IPAddressToString

#$ddns_ipv4 = [System.Net.Dns]::GetHostEntry('my.ipv4zone.ddns.tld')
echo LAN-IPv4:"    "$ipv4
echo WAN-IPv4:"    "$ddns_ipv4
echo LAN-IPv6:"    "$ipv6
echo WAN-IPv6:"    "$ddns_ipv6
```

OUTPUT AS:

```batch
LAN-IPv4:    172.16.12.10
WAN-IPv4:    151.14.98.172
LAN-IPv6:    fe80::325:be11:5aaa:2faa%7 2a00:22c3:113e:31aa:ffff:::31b3
WAN-IPv6:    2a00:22c3:113e:31aa:ffff:::31b3
```

What would be very helpful is if there is a better method to get this info inside of a variable to use in Powershell which is much more simplier and does not rely on my script either pinging / DNS recursive lookups from a Dynamic DNS provider.

Side note: I have been playing about with cURL (for the WAN-side lookups, using same method on my DynDNS A and AAAA Records) and as yet, have not quite managed to pipe the output of curl back into PowerShell $IP_Var solution has not reveled itself to me just yet.

-- There must be a simple way to achieve LAN/WAN-side IPv4/6 lookups all done from within  Powershell not having to rely on DDNS but directly from the network interface/routing table like maybe querying the *nbtstat -an* or something to this effect ...
Any suggestions welcomed. Thanks!

````
```lang-powershell-5.1
Working Local IPv4 and IPv6 address 
#BEGIN 
$ipv4 = Get-NetIPAddress -AddressFamily IPv4 -InterfaceIndex $(Get-NetConnectionProfile |
    Select-Object -ExpandProperty InterfaceIndex) | Select-Object -ExpandProperty IPAddress
$ipv6 = Get-NetIPAddress -AddressFamily IPv6 -InterfaceIndex $(Get-NetConnectionProfile |
    Select-Object -ExpandProperty InterfaceIndex) | Select-Object -ExpandProperty IPAddress

#Use DNS to Resolve WAN_IPv4 and WAN_IPv6 via [Systems.Net.Dns]
$ddns_ipv4 = ([System.Net.DNS]::GetHostAddresses('ipv4.ddns.tld') | 
    Where-Object {$_.AddressFamily -eq "InterNetwork"} | select-object IPAddressToString)[0].IPAddressToString
$ddns_ipv6 = ([System.Net.DNS]::GetHostAddresses('ipv6zone.ddns.tld') |
    Where-Object {$_.AddressFamily -eq "InterNetwork"} | select-object IPAddressToString)[0].IPAddressToString

#$ddns_ipv4 = [System.Net.Dns]::GetHostEntry('my.ipv4zone.ddns.tld')
echo LAN-IPv4:"    "$ipv4
echo WAN-IPv4:"    "$ddns_ipv4
echo LAN-IPv6:"    "$ipv6
echo WAN-IPv6:"    "$ddns_ipv6
````

OUTPUT AS:

```batch
LAN-IPv4:    172.16.12.10
WAN-IPv4:    151.14.98.172
LAN-IPv6:    fe80::325:be11:5aaa:2faa%7 2a00:22c3:113e:31aa:ffff:::31b3
WAN-IPv6:    2a00:22c3:113e:31aa:ffff:::31b3
```

Comment: From cmd.exe type >IPConfig/all which will give all the properties you are looking for.  In powershell you can use following to see all the properties : Get-NetIPAddress -AddressFamily IPv4 -InterfaceIndex  I think you want all that have : InterfaceAlias    : Wi-Fi

Comment: Try `Get-NetIPConfiguration -Detailed` to get at least IPv4 (LAN only) and IPv6 details in an easier way (including temporary IPv6 addresses per RFC4941). But to get the actual public IPv4, you have to do an external web request at least if you have a dynamic IP: Try `Invoke-RestMethod 'https://ifconfig.me/ip'` (doesn't work as expected with reverse proxies and vhosts)

Comment: PS: Keep in mind that the output of `Get-NetIPConfiguration -Detailed` could be an array and that the following properties (typeOf: `CimInstance[]`) are always arrays: AllIPAddresses, IPv6Address, IPv6TemporaryAddress, IPv6LinkLocalAddress, IPv4Address, IPv6DefaultGateway, IPv4DefaultGateway, DNSServer

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a way. Why? Because only the Router knows the WAN IP address and since the Router is effectively your DNS server, it never needs to inform your computer as to what the WAN IP ADDRESS is. The WAN IP address is beyond the scope of what your local computer will ever need to know "locally".

Now here is the freakin' script to get what you need. Just freakin' use it.

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms

# Retrieve WAN IP addresses
$wanIPv4 = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri 'http://api.ipify.org'
$wanIPv6 = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri 'http://api64.ipify.org'

# Create the form
$Form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$Form.Text = "WAN IP Addresses"
$Form.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(300,200)
$Form.StartPosition = "CenterScreen"

# Create the label for IPv4
$LabelIPv4 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$LabelIPv4.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10,10)
$LabelIPv4.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(280,20)
$LabelIPv4.Text = "WAN IPv4: $wanIPv4"

# Create the label for IPv6
$LabelIPv6 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$LabelIPv6.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10,40)
$LabelIPv6.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(280,20)
$LabelIPv6.Text = "WAN IPv6: $wanIPv6"

# Add the labels to the form
$Form.Controls.Add($LabelIPv4)
$Form.Controls.Add($LabelIPv6)

# Show the form
$Form.ShowDialog()

# RUN: powershell -ExecutionPolicy ByPass -File hello.ps1
```

#### Update base on comment

To execute the IP address retrieval and update the form on a timed basis, you can use a `System.Windows.Forms.Timer`. To extend the script to pipe the WAN IP address results into a JSON key/value format, you can modify the `Update-IPAddresses` function to also create a JSON object and write it to a file or handle it as needed. **I have also included a Last Updated label to the Form**. Here's the updated script:

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
Import-Module PowerShellGet

# Function to update IP addresses, convert to JSON, and update time
function Update-IPAddresses {
    $global:wanIPv4 = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri 'http://api.ipify.org'
    $global:wanIPv6 = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri 'http://api64.ipify.org'
    $LabelIPv4.Text = "WAN IPv4: $global:wanIPv4"
    $LabelIPv6.Text = "WAN IPv6: $global:wanIPv6"

    # Update the last updated label
    $global:LastUpdatedLabel.Text = "Last Updated: " + (Get-Date).ToUniversalTime().ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss") + " UTC"

    # Convert to JSON
    $ipInfo = @{
        WANIPv4 = $global:wanIPv4
        WANIPv6 = $global:wanIPv6
    }

    $json = $ipInfo | ConvertTo-Json
    Write-Output $json
    # Optional: Write to file
    # $json | Out-File "path\to\your\file.json"
}

# Create the form
$Form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$Form.Text = "WAN IP Addresses"
$Form.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(320,250)
$Form.StartPosition = "CenterScreen"

# Create labels
$LabelIPv4 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$LabelIPv4.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10,10)
$LabelIPv4.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(300,20)

$LabelIPv6 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$LabelIPv6.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10,40)
$LabelIPv6.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(300,20)

$global:LastUpdatedLabel = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$global:LastUpdatedLabel.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10,70)
$global:LastUpdatedLabel.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(300,20)

# Add the labels to the form
$Form.Controls.Add($LabelIPv4)
$Form.Controls.Add($LabelIPv6)
$Form.Controls.Add($global:LastUpdatedLabel)

# Timer setup
$Timer = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Timer
$Timer.Interval = 300000 # 5 minutes in milliseconds
$Timer.add_Tick({ Update-IPAddresses })
$Timer.Start()

# Initial update
Update-IPAddresses

# Show the form
$Form.ShowDialog()

# RUN: powershell -ExecutionPolicy ByPass -File hello.ps1
```

Comment: This is a very helpful script /methods where I could ultimately interrogate remote URI to gain WAN-side and plonk into $wanIPv4 and $wanIPv6 Vars, to use later on to pass back into my webhook calls. Your example has taken it a step further and displays the returned query into a simple UI form applet which can also get expanded upon with a simple info_dashboard sort of utility.. This is perfect! Next step is trying to figure out how to execute this on a flexible timed_loop() basis (~5m > 24hr) equiv to something like how in batch /timeout as a reference, then piped out results to json key/value

Comment: Hmmm... your script just gave me an idea for a personal project. Like a DynamicDNS Client of sorts.

Comment: This is practically perfect!
What would be neat is to have a Button in the UI Form if pressed, output the details to *.json file to the Current running directory or path from which was invoked 
~dp0\scripts\path\meta-info.json
As in:
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Drawing
$okButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
If run rightclick from Context-Menu this would be an all-in-one little power applet 
Idea and boilerplate example of my thought would be like this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/samples/creating-a-custom-input-box?view=powershell-7.3